# Detecting ctrl+left click on winforms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, events

How do I detect when the users holds ctrl and left clicks on a button in a windows forms application?

Comment: I'd upvote if this was asked a bit better - the answer is useful and Google found the question, but it... could be improved with a few words

Comment: @CodeJockey you could always edit the question and make it better for everyone.  Then upvote. :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to check the value of Form.ModifierKeys to see if Control was pressed, e.g.:

```
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            // Do Ctrl-Left Click Work
        }
    }
```

Comment: Careful! ModifierKeys is a bit-field, and multiple bits can be set if more than one modifier key is pressed at the same time. This code will only work if Control is pressed by itself.